# Duplicates of questions that only have a link-only answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, link-only-answers

Today, I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867433/automatic-layout-adjustment-to-varying-browser-window-size/29972821?noredirect=1) about fluid layouts in Flex.  After the OP asked about refining the technique, I realized that this question has been addressed before on Stackoverflow:

[Layout not giving height to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152984/layout-not-giving-height-to-container/9155404#9155404)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763061/flex-container-automatic-layout?rq=1

However, both of those questions have [the answer in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Is there a preferred way of dealing with these?  The obvious solution is to close as duplicate...but I hesitate to do that when the question it duplicates doesn't have a real answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag the non-answers, since they're not answers.

Since none of the duplicate questions have answers that are actually answers, don't close the newest question as a duplicate.